# how can i pass an object to a component using angular routing?

Tags: angular, typescript, url-routing, angular-router

I have an "home" component where I iterate my mangas (mangas is an array of objects) 
like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let manga of mangas">
  <h1> {{ manga.title }} </h1>
  <button routerLink="/manga/{{ manga.title }}"> read the manga </button>
</div>
```

(it's better than this but it's just to make an example)
so, how can I pass the entire "manga" object to the new route?
(i don't wanna to pass the entire array)

Comment: That is explained in the official angular documentation, the tour of heroes.
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#add-a-navigation-link-routerlink

See it working here
https://stackblitz.com/angular/pabodalxvjg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.component.html

You can see how the routes are configured
https://stackblitz.com/angular/pabodalxvjg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts

Answer (score 4):

if you want to pass an object to a router (not a simple parameter), you use "states" take a look [this links](https://netbasal.com/set-state-object-when-navigating-in-angular-7-2-b87c5b977bb)

```
<div *ngFor="let manga of mangas">
  <a routerLink="/manga" [state]="manga">
</div>
```

And get it in OnInit. Normally, if you use state to get an object, you usually want that, if no object, router to "home", If your object manga has a property, `mangaId` you can use this information inside the subscription

```
  constructor(public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap
      .pipe(map(() => window.history.state)).subscribe(res=>{
            console.log(res) //<--see thah you has an additional property:navigationId
            //you can check if you has passed an object really
            //If, e.g. your manga has a property mangaId<>0
            if (!res.mangaId) 
               router.navigate(['/home']                             
       })
  }
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but would you recommend such solution instead of using a  data store / services?

Comment: Before Angular 7, I used a service. I think the only reason to use either method is which method is the most comfortable for you, but I cannot recommend one over the other.

Answer (score 3):

You should not be passing the object itself in the route but rather the ID of the object and then retrieving the object from some type of datastore.

```
<div *ngFor="let manga of mangas">
  <h1> {{ manga.title }} </h1>
  <button routerLink="/manga/{{ manga.id }}"> 
     read the manga 
  </button>
</div>
```

In the spirit of a single page application, you might want to have a manga service (repository) that manages the collection of mangas.